# How do I insert the objects in my JSON Array into my db using Php?

Tags: php, json

In my Android app I create a JSON Array like :

```
[{"phone_number":"12345678"},{"phone_number":"23456789"},{"phone_number":"34567890"}, etc... etc...
```

My Android code looks like this :

```
public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";

 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
     //The KEY, KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber" . In PHP we will have $_POST["phonenumber"]
     //The VALUE, phonenumber, will be of the form "12345678"
        params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER,jsonArrayContacts.toString());
        return params;
}
```

How can I insert these phone numbers into my user table ?

I know the Php insert code itself is along the lines of :

```
$insert_into_user_command = "INSERT INTO user WHERE username = '$value'";
$insert_into_contacts_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_into_contacts_command);
```

But can you tell me the exact code ? Doing one individual value is easy enough, but can't figure out how to insert them in one POST.

I know I am on the right track as my response in Android shows me all the phone numbers in my JSON Array with :

```
require('dbConnect.php');

$json = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$array = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        echo $value->phone_number ;
    }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. This code is for personal use, will deal with security when going public.

Comment: It's not just for security. It's so you don't spend hours tracking down a stupid, avoidable bug related to escaping. Do it properly. It's not harder and it saves you a ton of time in the future.

Comment: I'm at such a beginner stage I find it easier to deal with the basics and know what's going on and then 'translate' it further down the line. A bit like a beginner's English students learning basic grammar and then jumping in later to tackle Chinese.

Comment: Imagine writing SQL code is like doing plumbing. There's a lot of ways you can sort of half-ass it and it will work at first, but over time it'll leak and start to break in all sorts of awful, ugly ways that are annoying and expensive to repair. If you do it right the first time you won't have problems like that. One line of code with `bind_param` fixes an entire class of bugs at the outset. You want to learn, that's great. My advice: Learn to do it the right way and you won't regret it.

Comment: what about mysql_real_escape_string ? That sufficient ?

Comment: It's a way of escaping, but it's also a ton more work than `bind_param` and if you ever forget you're setting yourself up for failure. Honestly, the easy way is `bind_param`. It keeps your query neat, uncluttered by data, and gives you complete control over how your data is bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');
$json = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$array = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {

        $phonenumber = $value->phone_number;
        $insert_into_user_command = "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES ('$phonenumber')";
        $insert_into_user_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_into_user_command);

    }

?>
```